# I can't run this project after import fron Github android

Tags: android, github, import

Hi I'm a beginner in android and I found a source code in Github that will help me in my final project but when I downloaded it , I can't make run ,there is no files in src just I need to know how to use the code and making run.

This is the project https://github.com/alexvasilkov/FoldableLayout

Answer (score 0):

Create an Android Project and add this as a Library its not a Standalone project.

then you can address to it like :

```
FoldableListLayout layout = ...
```

plus you can use it inside xml file.